# So how to redirect category to a page of the same name if it exists?

Tags: categories, wp-redirect

So I had previously tested a specific redirect where I knew the page exists.

```
function nepal_template_redirect() {
    if ( is_category( 'nepal' ) ) {
        $url = site_url( '/nepal' );
        wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
        exit();
    } } add_action( 'template_redirect', 'nepal_template_redirect' );
```

However what I really want to do is include a generic function that redirects any category where a page name exists of the same name. So I thought along these lines.

```
function pagefromcat_template_redirect()
{
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );
    if (page_exists($category_id))
    {
        $url = site_url( '/' . $category_id);
        wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
    }

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'pagefromcat_template_redirect' );
```

However there does not seem to be a codex item for anything like page_exists()

So how would I write a function to do this? Or is there an existing one that I have missed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I have it now. Largely due to @Michael - it requires of course that a category is exactly the same as a Page Title, but that is exactly what I want.

function pagefromcat_template_redirect()
{
    if ( ! is_category() ) {
        return;
    }

```
$category = get_queried_object();
// $page = get_page_by_path( $category->slug );  -- doesnt work
// $page = get_page_by_path( 'destinations/' . $category->slug); works but with deeper nested locations this will cause a problem, and we will have to have multiple prefixed locations
// atcivities immediately for instance.
$page = get_page_by_title($category->name);

if ( $page instanceof WP_Post )
{
    $url = get_permalink( $page );
    wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`get_page_by_path` does something similar:

```
function pagefromcat_template_redirect()
{
    if ( ! is_category() ) {
        return;
    }
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $page = get_page_by_path( $category->slug );
    if ( $page instanceof WP_Post )
    {
        $url = get_permalink( $page );
        wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
    }

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'pagefromcat_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Not sure I answered this appropriately as I added it as an answer - couldn't see how to add code whilst preserving line breaks - anyway response is below. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewSeabrook of course you need to replace `'Category Name'` with a variable containing the category name currently queried. Just so you know, the mentioned answer you posted is not always showing below this one and as it isn't an actual answer I am going to flag it accordingly, therefore it might get deleted by a moderator.

Comment: I updated my answer because you will have to use the category slug, ie. `my-pets`, and not the category name like `My Pets`.

Comment: I just edited @Michael's answer to reflect that the solution should be generic. Now it will bail if the query is not for a category and takes the queried category's slug to look for a page.

Comment: Ok -so this is not working -its not redirecting - to answer @Michael previous comment about the echo - this was purely added in there so that I could trace the execution through the code via the browser. Embedding echos in your code above again I see that $category->slug contains the correct value, but $page->slug is empty. So it dawns on me that different directory structures, might be an issue, will test and see if it makes a difference.
https://adventurebods.com/destinations/british-columbia/
https://adventurebods.com/category/destinations/north-america/canada/british-columbia/

Comment: I tested this code with a setup of `/category/parentcat/childcat` and it redirects to the page `/childcat` as expected. I also don't understand what you mean by `$page->slug`; a category object does not have the same properties as a post object.

Comment: Ok $page->slug perhaps does not exist, I wrongly assumed that as a category object has a property named slug, so would a page object. I am not overly familiar with WP objects or framework hence my difficulties with this problem and appreciation of your help. So as my scenario is not redirecting, what might be blocking and what might I include to provide feedback to verify the step that's failing?

Comment: It's the usual PHP debugging procedure: debug return statements, variables, conditional statements etc. to find the line that creates an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Been a while but finally had the time to revisit this. Thanks to your code @Michael I am a bit closer having now setup a local development environment so that I can step through the code more effectively.
The line with the issue then is this: $page = get_page_by_path( $category->slug );
and the problem is that I have child pages. So this works $page = get_page_by_path( 'destinations/' . $category->slug); however this is going to cause issues as the pages will be nested deeper, i.e Destinations - USA - California - Los Angeles ...etc So destinations hardcoded is not going to cut it.

Comment: I see that I could also use get_page_hierarchy() but an additional problem has occured that on the local server, the request having stepped through the code correctly the first time, it is not subsequently passing the is_category() test, rather it returns from the function, and I have altered no other statement. But also wiredly if I comment out the entire content of the pagefromcat_template_redirect() function incredably it still redirects!!! I am guessing this is to do with some sort of caching with XDebug under Netbeans. I dont know how to resolve this though as yet.

Comment: So I have resolved the issue now but, if anybody uses Netbeans or Xdebug nad has any comment about the behaviour I mentionned in the previous comment I would be happy to hear it. Rebooting though not for that reason cleared the issue. Is there a local-cache setting or anything like that - that I can turn off while debugging.