# Automatically redirect a page to a category that share the same slug

Tags: categories, pages, redirect, slug

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/315490/so-how-to-redirect-category-to-a-page-of-the-same-name-if-it-exists) shows me how to redirect a category to a page that share the same slug, but how would I redirect a page to a category with the same slug?

e.g. `abc.com/slug` ---> `abc.com/category/sub/slug`

Comment: Do you mean posts or pages or cpt? By default pages do not have categories like posts do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can just turn the code 180 degrees from the linked question and problem solved.

Just kidding.

I would start with getting the current page slug, using that slug search for a category that has that slug, if found, redirect to it

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'bt_redirect_page_to_category');
function bt_redirect_page_to_category () {
    // if we are not in page, no need to run the code
    if (!is_page()) return;

    // get current page object
    global $post;

    // get page slug
    $slug = $post->post_name;

    // the term taxonomy
    $taxonomy = 'category';

    // get category
    // you can use get_category_by_slug(), but I prefer get_term_by()
    $category = get_term_by('slug', $slug, $taxonomy);

    // if no category found, no need to continue with the code
    if (empty($category)) return;

    // found category so we can redirect
    if ( wp_safe_redirect( get_term_link( $category, $taxonomy ), 301 ) ) {
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: ps: I wonder if OP means posts not pages. I think `get_queried_object()/get_post()` within the post/page would allow us  to skip the use of the global reference :-)

Comment: @birgire What I understood is that there is no connection between the two. just if, for example, I go to a page `contact us` that has a slug `contact-us` he would like to redirect to a category with that same slug, but they have no actual connection. Also thank you for the exit, completely forgot about it.

Comment: Yes that is correct, no relationship between the page and category except for the same slug.